# How to match value against array and set variables?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to set a user's Active Directory city,address,state,zip based on what someone selects for the user's office location.

I have a winform that has various drop down menus for title, department, location.
When the location is chosen, I want that to automatically set the address,city,state,zip without having to enter it manually.

The location field is stored as `$locationcombobox.text` which has the following options:

```
Office
Office1
Office2
Office3
Office4
Office5
Office6
```

My array looks similar to this:

```
City      State  Office 
----      -----  ------ 
Newark    NJ     Office1
Portland  ME     Office2
New York  NY     Office3
Dallas    TX     Office4
Denver    CO     Office5
Atlanta   GA     Office6
```

When someone selects `Office1` in the combobox, Id like it to set `$city = Newark` and `$state=NJ`.
I'm sure I am overthinking this, but I don't have much experience with calling arrays.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF/XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn your array into a hashtable, using the `Office` property as the key. This way you can easily look up the `City` and `State` values based on Office:

```
# Create empty hashtable
$OfficeLookup = @{}

# Add the array items to the table
$MyArray |ForEach-Object {
    $OfficeLookup[$_.Office] = $_
}
```

Now, you can easily grab the values like:

```
$Office = $OfficeLookup[$locationcombobox.text]
$City = $Office.City
$State = $Office.State
```

Comment: Mathias, I would like to embed the hashtable into a script so that I dont have to import the csv each time. I wrote the hashtable out but I get an array index evaluated to null. Thoughts?